# Mapping dictionary onto dataframe when dictionary key is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary where the values are lists:

```
dict = {1: ['a','b'], 2:['c', 'd']}
```

I want to map the dictionary onto col1 of my dataframe.

```
col1    
 a     
 c
```

If the value of col1 is IN one of the values of my dictionary, then I want to replace the value of col1 with the value of the dictionary key.

Like this, my dataframe will become:

```
col1
 1
 2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Lists are not hashable and you cannot use them as dictionary keys. Probably you mean tuple or another iterable and hashable object.

Comment: sorry, I mixed up the keys and values. Edited the question.

Comment: OK, now please update your question with the code that you've tried and tell us about the problems that you've encountered so far.

Comment: you are using dictionaries on the from way. From values to keys, which is not the use case of dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the dictionary in the right way:

```
mapping = {}
for key, values in D.items():
    for item in values:
        mapping[item] = key
```

and then

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(mapping)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `stack` + `reset_index` and `set_index` with `map`.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({1: ['a','b'], 2:['c', 'd']})
mapping = d.stack().reset_index().set_index(0)["level_1"]
s = pd.Series(['a', 'c'], name="col1")  
s.map(mapping)
0    1
1    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Step by step demo

```
d.stack()

0  1    a
   2    c
1  1    b
   2    d
dtype: object

d.stack().reset_index()

    level_0 level_1 0
0   0          1    a
1   0          2    c
2   1          1    b
3   1          2    d

d.stack().reset_index().set_index(0)

   level_0  level_1
0       
a       0        1
c       0        2
b       1        1
d       1        2
```

Finally, we select the `level_1` column as our mapping to pass in `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this???

```
D = {1 : ['a', 'b'], 2 : ['c', 'd']}

for key, value in D.items():
    for each in value:
        if each in D[key]:
            print(each, "is in D[%s]" % key)
```

o/p:

```
a is in D[1]
b is in D[1]
c is in D[2]
d is in D[2]
```